# Does swift allow code blocks without conditions/loops to reduce local variable scope?

Tags: swift, scope, swift2

In languages with block level scope, I sometimes create arbitrary blocks just so I can encapsulate local variables and not have them pollute their parents' scope:

```
func myFunc() {
  // if statements get block level scope
  if self.someCondition {
    var thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere = true
    self.doSomethingElse(thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere)
  }

  // many languages allow blocks without conditions/loops/etc
  {
    var thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere = false
    self.doSomething(thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere)
  }
}
```

When I do this in Swift, it thinks I'm creating a closure and doesn't execute the code. I could create it as a closure and immediately execute, but that seems like it would come with execution overhead (not worth it just for code cleanliness).

```
func myFunc() {
  // if statements get block level scope
  if self.someCondition {
    var thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere = true
    self.doSomethingElse(thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere)
  }

  // converted to closure
  ({
    var thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere = false
    self.doSomething(thisVarShouldntExistElsewhere)
  })()
}
```

Is there support for something like this in Swift?

Comment: These are my favorites:

https://gist.github.com/fluidityt/a87a3d0d74660786e466ea59d1e2d39f

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `do` statement to create arbitrary scope in Swift. For example:

```
func foo() {
    let x = 5

    do {
        let x = 10
        print(x)
    }
}

foo() // prints "10"
```

As per [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/do-statement):

> The do statement is used to introduce a new scope and can optionally
>   contain one or more catch clauses, which contain patterns that match
>   against defined error conditions. Variables and constants declared in
>   the scope of a do statement can be accessed only within that scope.
>
> A do statement in Swift is similar to curly braces (`{}`) in C used to
>   delimit a code block, and does not incur a performance cost at
>   runtime.
>
> Ref: *The Swift Programming Language - Language Guide - Statements - Do Statement*

Comment: Oh, perfect! I've only ever used those with repeat conditions so I didn't think of it.

Comment: Damn, I didn't know about this. I would've thought to use an anon closure: `_ = { print("foo") }()`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Jack Lawrence's answer is to use blocks; similar to the block in your first code snippet.

```
func foo () {
    let x = 5

    let block = {
        let x = 10
        print(x)
    }

    block()
}

foo()
```

Comment: This isn't really different from the OP's blocks solution. You're just assigning the block to a variable before executing it.